# Is there an post Drag and Drop event?

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement drag and drop capability into a custom data grid control.  In the end, I'd like to be able to drag rows between 2 of these custom data grids.  I believe I have everything working as expected.  However, I need to do some cleanup in the drag and drop source control.  Specifically, I need to refresh the grids after items are moved.  How do I do this?  If it make any difference, these grids are not bound to a data source (for other reasons I won't explain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You supposed to perform post-drop operation on the drag source in the [`MouseMove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove.aspx) event handler after the call to [`DoDragDrop()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.dodragdrop.aspx) returned and on the drop target in the [`DragDrop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragdrop.aspx) event handler.